# Remove duplicate rows based on columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I will like to ask a question on removing duplicate rows based on columns (2 column)

So for instance, I have constructed a dataframe below:

```
 country     city           date                col_d 
 Singapore   Singapore     2020-07-17 09:00     5
 Singapore   Singapore     2020-07-17 18:00     5
 Malaysia    Johor Bahru   2020-07-17 09:00     5
 Malaysia    Johor Bahru   2020-07-17 18:00     6
 Singapore   Singapore     2020-07-18 09:00     0
 Singapore   Singapore     2020-07-18 18:00     10
 Malaysia    Johor Bahru   2020-07-19 09:00     0
 Malaysia    Johor Bahru   2020-07-19 18:00     6
 Malaysia    Senlangor     2020-07-19 09:00     6
```

I will like to do an operation, which is to remove duplicate rows based on 'date' and 'city'.

- For date - I will only want the last row to remain, meaning the
  timing of 18:00 should remain.
- For city - only if there are
  duplicates, for instance Singapore / Johor Bahru, only the last row
  of the timing of 18:00 should stay.
- Notice that the col_d has different values too, which is why I
  want the row of 18:00 to remain    if it is there.

So the correct DF should look like below:

```
 country     city           date                col_d 
 Singapore   Singapore     2020-07-17 18:00     5
 Malaysia    Johor Bahru   2020-07-17 18:00     6
 Singapore   Singapore     2020-07-18 18:00     10
 Malaysia    Johor Bahru   2020-07-19 18:00     6
 Malaysia    Senlangor     2020-07-19 09:00     6
```

I have used the below code, but it appears that the duplicated rows based on date are not dropping off.

So firstly, I converted the 'date' column to datetime format first.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
```

As the data are already sorted by ascending order, I do not add in the additional code to sort it by ascending order.

So it looks like this:

```
 country     city          date            col_d 
 Singapore   Singapore     2020-07-17      5
 Singapore   Singapore     2020-07-17      5
 Malaysia    Johor Bahru   2020-07-17      5
 Malaysia    Johor Bahru   2020-07-17      6
 Singapore   Singapore     2020-07-18      0
 Singapore   Singapore     2020-07-18      10
 Malaysia    Johor Bahru   2020-07-19      0
 Malaysia    Johor Bahru   2020-07-19      6
 Malaysia    Senlangor     2020-07-19      6
```

After which, I used the below code to 'drop' all duplicate rows, while keeping 'last'. As per above, it does not work.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['date','city'], keep='last')
```

Anyone can help me out on this? Appreciate!

Comment: remove the `.dt.date` while converting to `datetime`

Comment: you created a new column named `Date` but when dropping the duplicates you still refer to the old `date` column, replace that with the new `Date` column..?: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date','city'], keep='last')`

Comment: thanks yall! Silly mistake there. I created a new column to remove .dt.date and subsequently drop based on the new column. That seemed to work!